# How to use != with OR in a SELECT statement

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a list of applicants which includes two fields, accept and waitlist.  For each of the fields accept and waitlist the possible values are blank (not yet considered), Yes (accepted or waitlisted) or No (rejected).

I want to extract one display to show  a list of applicants in which either or both waitlist and accept are set to "Yes". The following does exactly what I want.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM applicants WHERE waitlist = 'Yes' OR accept = 'Yes' ORDER BY lname,fname ASC";
```

I also want to display a list of those applicants who have not yet been considered or have been rejected so the value of waitlist or accept is blank or "No". The following, which seemed an obvious modification of the first statement, does not eliminate anyone.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM applicants WHERE accept != 'Yes' OR waitlist != 'Yes' ORDER BY lname,fname ASC";
```

If I eliminate the OR statement I can at least just see a list of those who have not been accepted. Modifying the query to make the selections positive, ie.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM applicants WHERE accept = 'No' OR accept = '' OR waitlist = 'No OR waitlist = '' ORDER BY lname,fname ASC";
```

works for either accept or waitlist but simply results in a display of all applicants if both fields are included.

I'm sure this has been asked before but I can't find it.

Comment: Actually, for someone to be 'not considered', they have to be BOTH not accepted **AND** not waitlisted, right?

Comment: I'm having a hard time following. Can you post sample data/schema with the result you're getting and ones you want?

Comment: Yes, table structure will be very appreciated.

Comment: If you're wanting both, use `AND` not `OR`, if that's what the question's about or use a subquery.

Comment: You are probably looking for something around this idea: `SELECT * FROM applicants WHERE (accept == 'no'  OR waitlist == 'no') OR (accept != 'yes' AND waitlist != 'yes');`. Maybe just the second parentheses, since `no` is already different to `yes`

Comment: I've stayed here waiting for an update to the question but you seem to either have logged off or ignoring those comments; I've left the question with an unclear vote to close. Good luck.

Comment: _so the value of waitlist or accept is blank or "No"._ ... personally this isn't the best idea, your waitlist or accept should have two states because in this case that's the only options, having NULL should not be an option. With this being said, then you could do the following code: `SELECT * FROM applicants WHERE accept = 'NO' AND waitlist = 'NO' ORDER BY lname,fname ASC`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using OR when you want to use AND.

```
SELECT * FROM applicants WHERE accept != 'Yes' OR waitlist != 'Yes';
```

> I'm accepted, I'm not on the waiting list. --> waitinglist=='' so I'm returned
>
> I'm on the waiting list, I'm not accepted yet. --> accepted=='' so I'm also retuned
>
> I'm not on the waiting list, I'm also not accepted yet. --> accepted=='' AND waitinglist=='' so I'm also retuned

Instead use `AND`

```
SELECT * FROM applicants WHERE accept != 'Yes' AND waitlist != 'Yes';
```

Case:

> I'm accepted, I'm not on the waiting list. --> waitinglist=='' so I'm NOT returned
>
> I'm on the waiting list, I'm not accepted yet. --> accepted=='' so I'm also NOT retuned
>
> I'm not on the waiting list, I'm also not accepted yet. --> accepted=='' AND waitinglist=='' so I'm retuned

Comment: Following on all your answers is that I also want the list to show applicants for whom accepted == 'No' so that the person handling this information can identify them from the list.  Ministry of Chaps is correct, that waitlist only needs two states, blank or yes because someone who is definitely not accepted is not put on the waitlist. With that data correction in place and using AND not OR

Comment: as follows $query = "SELECT * FROM applicants WHERE  accept != 'Yes' AND waitlist = '' "; I'm getting the display  that I wanted.  Thank you all.